Unprotect/Clear only within a local context
I'm working on a project, and I want to Unprotect and ClearAll the properties of NonCommutativeMultiply, but only within a local context. I want  my .wl package to use a new definition for NCM that I have control over, but I don't want to change the behavior of it outside of the functions in the package. Is there a way to accomplish this using Modules?

Overriding system commands can be very dangerous. If I were you, I would temporarily change the heads by /. {NonCommutativeMultiply->myNonCommutativeMultiply}, and after your work is done, restore by /. {myNonCommutativeMultiply->NonCommutativeMultiply}.

There is no real way to do that without some serious meta-programming, because once the package is loaded, the context will be Global again so you're no longer inside the package. Honestly you should give some concrete examples of what you want exactly, because this is quite a vague question.

This sounds like you probably want Block
